# What method logical for lock my home screen button android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm making a lock screen application on Android, I've gotten an event when the home button is pressed but I can't figure out how or what method to prevent the user from exiting the application via the Home button..

I use the method when the Home button is pressed then call the application back but this way there is a delay and still exits the application, maybe someone knows and can give me a little idea or technical for this case..

Thanks in advance..

here my button home event  in log
`action:android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS,reason:homekey`

my recent app event in log
`action:android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS,reason:recentapps`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The home button is a system button, there is no way to override the behavior of it.  This is because any app that prevents you leaving it, other than a kiosk app, is pretty much malware by definition-  you should never prevent the user from leaving your app.  And if you're building a kiosk app, you'd be making it a launcher (I'd also highly recommend not using React Native for that, as the performance is low and a launcher needs to be lightweight to lead quickly.